# Why it's printing [[1234],[1234]] when I didn't assign an empty list to b

Tags: python, list

```
a=[1234]
#b=[]
b.append(a)
print(b)
output: [[1234], [1234]]
a=[1234]
b=[]
b.append(a)
#print(b)
#output:[[1234]]
```

I could not understand the above code when I assigned an empty list to b it's printing [[1234]] but without assigning if I append it to b it prints out [[1234],[1234]].

What's happening here?

Comment: In the first case you will get `NameError` as `b` is not defined. The second case will work as expected.

Comment: The first case would raise a compile error. I am not sure how you get the output.

Comment: when i create an empty list b=[] the list object is created and the element a is added and the output is [[1234]] but as soon as I comment #b=[] the object created is not destroyed instead the b.append(a) keeps on adding a which is [1234]  everytime when I run. Can somebody explain how ?. Really thankful for the help

Comment: are you using jupyter-notebook ? or ipython?

Comment: kederrac is asking, because you are clearly not restarting from scratch if a and b persist between runs. Rerunning a cell would do this.

Comment: @kederrac- I used jupyter notebooks now I rectified my mistake and it does not erase from it memory so thats why this confusion

Comment: @viennaMike- I got it so we need to rerun the cell if its still there then restart the kernel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using `jupyter-notebook` you could get this behavior, I suppose that you run the same cell 2 times, one time with `b=[]` uncomment and one time with `#b=[]`, from one run to other in `jupyter` the variables are stored in memory so for the second run your `b` is already equal with `[[1234]]`, equivalent code for your second run of your `jupyter cell`:

```
b = [[1234]] # aready in memory

a=[1234]
#b=[]
b.append(a)
print(b)
```

output:

```
[[1234], [1234]]
```

Comment: It really helped me I tried with jupyter notebooks it really helped me a lot thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

You likely already have b previous defined somewhere. When you set b=[] the second time, b is cleared. You can not call append on an array that is not defined. If you run just the following code:

```
a=[1234]
b.append(a)
print(b)
```

you should get the following error when it goes through the interpreter.

```
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

Comment: More precisely, `b` is not cleared, but the name `b` is set to an empty list. Whatever `b` *used* to refer to is left unchanged (though possibly eligible for garbage collection).

Comment: I am a beginner so I could not understand but now I was able to understand.thanks